# How to send emojicons icons when click on button in Android?

Tags: android, xmpp

1.I am making an chatting application, in which during chatting, I want to send emoticons icons when selects from the dialog and then click on send button, it should show that particular image.

2.when I am clicking on send button, it's sending to user and shows, but the problem is that I want to show the image on the place of a name, but it's showing me like this

[image]

like "4.png" or "2.png".
I want to display the image which I have selected. What should I do? I am confused, please help me.here is my code

```
 smilee.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {

            if (!popupWindow.isShowing()) 
            {
                popupWindow.setHeight((int) (keyboardHeight));

                if (isKeyBoardVisible) {
                    emoticonsCover.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
                } else {
                    emoticonsCover.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                }
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(parentLayout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

            } else {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }

        }});
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {

            String text = mSendText.getText().toString().trim();

            Spanned sp = mSendText.getText();                   
            //chats.add(sp);
            //content.setText("");

            mSendText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s1), null);
            if(commanInstance.checkInternetConn(getApplicationContext()))
            {
                if(commanInstance.getConnection().isConnected())
                {
                    if(text.length()!=0)
                    {
                        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Sending text [" + text + "] to [" + to + "]");

                        Chat chat = null;
                        chat = commanInstance.getConnection().getChatManager().createChat(to, XMPPClient.this);
                        chat_imageview.setEnabled(true);

                        /*
                         * send msg
                         */
                        Message             message = new Message(chat.getParticipant(), Message.Type.chat);
                        message.setThread(chat.getThreadID());
                        String messagePacketID=message.getPacketID();
                        //message.setProperty("Time", commanInstance.getCurrentTime());
                        message.setThread(commanInstance.getCurrentTime());
                        message.setBody(text);

                        MessageEventManager.addNotificationsRequests(message, true, true, true, true);
                        try {
                            chat.sendMessage(message);
                            sendCancelledNotification(to);

                        } catch (XMPPException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        /*
                         * add msg in list item
                         */
                        /*
                         * insert into database
                         *
                         */
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
                        Date date = new Date();

                        String[] toYou=to.split("@");




                        ItemTwoLine act=new ItemTwoLine(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher),changeNameToCapital(getUserName())+"#:#"+text+"#:#"+"Sent","Me"+"#:#"+commanInstance.getCurrentTime()+"#:#"+messagePacketID,true,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check));
                        commanInstance.getCustomeList(listKeyValue).add(act);
                        int positionOfItem=commanInstance.getCustomeList(listKeyValue).indexOf(act);
                        db.addContact(new Contact(getUserName(),toYou[0],changeNameToCapital(getUserName())+"#:#"+text+"#:#"+"Sent","Me"+"#:#"+commanInstance.getCurrentTime()+"#:#"+messagePacketID,"Sent","Out","garvage","garvage",String.valueOf(positionOfItem),dateFormat.format(date)));



                        db.close();
                        /*
                         * Mantain open conversation screen list
                         */

                        //  String valForOpen=openCon[0]+"#:#"+text;

                        /*
                         * End open conversation screen list and start refersh list
                         */

                        if(t)
                        {
                            list.setAdapter(adapter);

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            t=false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        mSendText.setText("");
                        scrollMyListViewToBottom();
                        /*
                         * set alarm
                         */
                        //setAlarm(openCon[0]);
                        /*
                         * set alarm end
                         */


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Here is my *adapter class*

```
Msg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Msg);
            //Msg.setText(Html.fromHtml(nameAndText[1] ));

            //               TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.TextView2 );
            SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(nameAndText[1]);
            //Bitmap smiley = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.emoticon );

            //ssb.setSpan(smiley, 16, 17, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );    
            Msg.setText( ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library.

https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon

It has custom text views and controls which are capable to displaying the smileys and also handles converting them to unicode.

I used this with our chat application and it worked like a charm, even saving them in database is very easy.

Comment: your answer is good,but i have seen this,in this example,fragment class is used,but i am making my application without fragment

Comment: Yes, we too faced the problem of showing the fragment in a popup window. So we had to use a workaround by hiding and displaying a layout when the smiley icons are needed. We were able to get it close to the way whatsapp shows its keyboard and smileys, but there is a slight lag in slower mobiles. If you don't to use fragments its a pain to customise this example.

Answer (score 1):

use this code may help to send the emojisicon with the text

```
textview.setText(getSmiledText(text.toString()));

     public Spannable getSmiledText(String text) {
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
    if (emoticons.size() > 0) {
        int index;
        for (index = 0; index < builder.length(); index++) {
            if (Character.toString(builder.charAt(index)).equals(":")) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : emoticons.entrySet()) {
                    int length = entry.getKey().length();
                    if (index + length > builder.length())
                        continue;
                    if (builder.subSequence(index, index + length).toString().equals(entry.getKey())) {
                        builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getContext(), entry.getValue()), index, index + length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        index += length - 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return builder;
}
```

first create the heap for the emoticons,try this.

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> emoticons = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

emoticons.put(":-)", R.drawable.f01);
emoticons.put(":P", R.drawable.f02);
emoticons.put(":D", R.drawable.f03);
```

Comment: use in any activity,d'nt confuse.

Comment: sir i am taking my image from assets folder.,then what i do..for that?

Comment: put your all image in drawable folder and from that you allocate the spannable text with corresponding emojis icon in hashmap,this is the one of the way to get the solutions.