# Show native emoji keyboard on button click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-softkeyboard, emoji

I have the codes below that shows the keyboard on button click. How can I modify the code so the native emoji keyboard pops up?

```
    Button smiley=(Button) findViewById(id.btnSmiley);
    smiley.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
        }
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422120/android-how-to-send-emojicons-icons-when-click-on-button

Comment: set native emoji keyboard in keyboard setting of your android phone to treat it as the default keyboard

Comment: Has nobody an answer to this? need this, too

Comment: @Clyde please answer the question how you resolved this